# Is it possible to use AppThemeBinding in Android Custom Styles?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement Darkmode for Android by using the new [AppThemeBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes). It works fine for Android and iOS but i do not have a clue on how to implement it for custom renderers or custom styles.

For example i got a custom Stepper renderer which looks something like this:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control != null)
    {
        Android.Widget.Button buttonDown = (Android.Widget.Button)Control.GetChildAt(0);
        Android.Widget.Button buttonUp = (Android.Widget.Button)Control.GetChildAt(1);
        if(e.NewElement != null)
        {
            //Button Down
            buttonDown.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.button_bg_left);
            buttonDown.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DpToPixel(50), DpToPixel(33));
            buttonDown.SetPadding(0,0,0,0);
            buttonDown.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#007bff"));
            //Button Up
            buttonUp.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.button_bg_right);
            buttonUp.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DpToPixel(50), DpToPixel(33));
            buttonUp.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            buttonUp.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#007bff"));
                  
        }
    }
}
```

I'm setting a background resource which is a `.xml` file and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#007bff" />
    <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Since the AppThemeBinding is a Markup Extension and works inside `.xaml` files, i have no clue how i could implement color changes for my android specific renderers?

How could i go about changing the color of my custom shape for Light/Darkmode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [Detect the current system theme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#detect-the-current-system-theme) in the renderer and then set the corresponding color:

```
class MyStepperRenderer : StepperRenderer
{
    public MyStepperRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        OSAppTheme currentTheme = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.RequestedTheme;

        if (currentTheme == OSAppTheme.Light)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, that works for my custom renderers! But one thing i'm still curious. I got my `styles.xml` file where i define my theme colors which is referenced in the `MainActivity.cs`. How would i go about changing these colors to respond on AppTheme changes?

Comment: You mean you can't get the color from `styles.xml` in the renderer?

Comment: No - i mean by setting the theme like `Theme = "@style/MainTheme"` colors like `colorPrimary` or `colorAccent` are used for certain elements in Xamarin.Forms, like for example if i got a TableView the title of a section is automatically colored in one of these colors without a custom renderer. Do i have to create a custom renderer to change the colors depending on the current `OSAppTheme`?

Comment: No, if it is in Xamarin.forms, you can set the color directly by: `<Label Text="This text is green in light mode, and red in dark mode."
               TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Green, Dark=Red}" />`. Like the code in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#appthemebinding-markup-extension).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's not directly in Forms. Take a simple picker for example - in Android the Picker has a colored line underneath that changes as soon as you click it. I'm controlling these colors with the `Theme` that i set in my `MainActivity`, however these colors are only defined in a `.xml` file and not in a custom renderer.

Comment: I don't know if I understand right. While you can get and set any color in custom renderer like the color you defined in .xml. If you want to change the color of a certain element, you can change it in custom render or forms if possible.